# Calendar sync with Google Calendar notification time

Tags: google-calendar

Events sync-ed from Google Calendar have a default notification time of 10 minutes in advance. Sometimes that's not enough.

Is there any way to automate this and have the default be something else?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Google Calendar on the web you can set a default notification period for the events you subsequently set up on the web calendar.  In the calendar app provided with Gingerbread I don't see any similar default setting but you can set a notification for each event you set up.

FYI Google has numerous problems with alarms in Gingerbread.  One is that if you subsequently change an alarm that was set up in the web calendar using the web calendar that change may not sync to the phone.  Another is that eventually notifications will start coming late and there is no known fix (in spite of Google presumably knowing about it for almost a year although they've only apparently actually acknowledged knowing about it for about six months).

Answer (score 0):

You can also create default notification for each calendar (group of events)(the default group is simply "Event").

1. open calendar
2. select menu (top left)
3. scroll down to settings
4. under your email select your calendar (click on show more if you have more than one otherwise select "Event")
5. choose a default color and notifications.

Each of your email/ "calendar" can have its own defauls color/notifications.

This will only be a template, you will still be able to set the color and  nofications when you create/edit a particular event.